# ¿como hago para imprimir el valor de return en la siguiente funcion?

Tags: python

o no tienen retorno la siguiente funcion por que se si el retorno de una funcion puede ser un string

````
menu = int(input("coloca el valor de menu"))
def ejemplo_de_funcion():
    print("el valor de menu es = ",menu)
    print("por tanto entra al ejemplo de Cómo Crear y llamar Funciones (Python)")
    print("esto es una funcion en\npython")
    print("fin del ejemplo de Cómo Crear y llamar Funciones (Python)")
    print("y por lo tanto")
    print("fin de la funcion")
    return "ejemplo de Cómo Crear y llamar Funciones (Python)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

como tu funcion hace todo los demas print y devuelve un string.
Solo tienes que guardar el valor retornado y hacer un print de tal valor.

```
result = ejemplo_de_funcion()
print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

Podés imprimir directamente el llamado a la función, y así se va a imprimir lo que está en el Return (antes se van a ejecutar todos los prints de la función). Así:

```
print(ejemplo_de_funcion())
```